# C# datagrid specific cell editable

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell, editing

I want to enable a specific cell for editing.

My datagridview is readonly false.

and on cell click i get my columnindex and try to do :

```
     if (e.ColumnIndex == 7)
                {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["id"].Value)))
                    {
                        dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly = false;
                        dgv.BeginEdit(true);
                        dgv.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Selected = true;
                    }


                }
```

without success, my cell stay disable.
Could someone help.
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824813/in-datagridview-turn-readonly-property-of-column-to-false-when-adding-new-row-o

Comment: Is it possible that the code is setting the WHOLE grid to read only? If the whole grid is set to read only… then the “grids” read only property will “override” ANY read only commands specific to rows, columns or cells. If this is the case, then you will need to set the “grids” read only property to `false` before you can edit any row, column or cell. To avoid this, you can loop through the individual rows, columns or cells and individually set them to read only, then your code should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this code :

```
private void dgvLocataire_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
       {
           dgvLocataire.BeginEdit(false);

           var ec = dgvLocataire.EditingControl as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
           if (ec != null && ec.Width - e.X < SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth)
               ec.DroppedDown = true;

           if ((e.ColumnIndex != 5) && (e.ColumnIndex != 6) && (e.ColumnIndex != 7))
           {
               dgvLocataire.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly = true;
           }

       }
```

Thanks for your help